# gitlab-ci skipped the manual step and continue

Tags: linux, gitlab-ci

I have the following GitLab-ci YAML file. the manual job gets skipped, and the pipeline completes successfully even though the manual job did not get triggered.

How can I fix it and why did this happen?

```
stages:
  - stage1
  - stage2

job1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - echo "this is an automatic job"

manual_job:
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - echo "This is a manual job"
  when: manual
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because manual jobs are considered optional, and do not need to run.

> Internally, manual jobs have allow_failure set to true by default, which means that these skipped manual jobs do not cause a pipeline failure. The YAML code below demonstrates how to write the manual job, which results in the same behavior. The job doesn't automatically start, is skipped, and the pipeline passes.

```
stages:
  - stage1
  - stage2

job1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - echo "this is an automatic job"

manual_job:
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - echo "This is a manual job"
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
```

You can set allow_failure to true for any job, including both manual and automatic jobs, and then the pipeline does not care if the job runs successfully or not.

Comment: That's work. Thank you